# How do I get dynamic change of height in rows or cells?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How to get dynamic height in a cell?
If I put too much text in a cell it will not show all the info since it's not room for it. I want my calcsheet to dynamically change the height in the entire row when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Highlight the cells you want to format in this way.
2. From the `Format` menu, select `Cells...` (keyboard shortcut Ctrl+1).
3. Go to the `Alignment` tab.
4. Check `Wrap text automatically`.
5. Click `OK`.

Comment: Thanks for that fast reply JBentley. I was trying that just before I posted but couldn't get it working. Still can't. :-/

Comment: @user3112008 It works for me in a fresh spreadsheet. There is one caveat: cells won't automatically decrease their height when you remove text from them. That has to be done semi-manually by selecting the rows, and double clicking on one of the lines which separate the row labels on the left had side. Every row you selected will then have their heights recalculated. I'm not sure why it behaves like this, but it is the same in Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Ah. good to know. Just realized It's because I'm trying to perform it in merged cells. Any workarounds for this? Assume not. Just have to redo the entire shubang. I'm on Libre office 3 btw.

Comment: @AndersBrontosaurus I'm not sure. When I create a fresh spreadsheet, merge two cells, enter enough text for it to be truncated, and then perform the steps above, it correctly adjusts the height. My version is 3.6.3.2

Comment: Strange JBentley. I made a new spreadsheet and got it working at the start but suddenly it doesn't any longer. Avoided all merging. Have done some changes to the cells but nothing special. I will have to examine deeper just when it stops working and post back. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4):

1. Select all the cells
2. go to `Format`->`Row`->`Optimal Height`
3. Check `Default Value` and click `OK`

Answer (score 1):

- Select all the table.
- Go to Format > Cells and check Wrap Text.
- Also "Filled" in the drop-down under Text Alignment.

That worked for me after trying all the other things. :)